# Python memoized with **kwargs when calling a function doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, memoization

The call to GetData1 works well and prints:

```
hello 67 8.3
```

the call to GetData2 fails:

```
TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arg1'
```

My code is

```
class Memoized(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        print args
        with Locker:
            try:
                return self.cache[args]
            except KeyError:
                self.cache[args] = value = self.func(*args)
                return value


def GetData1(arg1, arg2, arg3) :
    print arg1, arg2, arg3

@Memoized
def GetData2(arg1, arg2, arg3) :
    print arg1, arg2, arg3



r = { 'arg1' : 'hello', 'arg2': 67, 'arg3' : 8.3 }
GetData1(**r)
GetData2(**r)
```

Comment: Whenever you say 'does not work', tell us *what doesn't work*. Specify what happens, what you expected to happen instead. Don't expect us to *guess*.

Comment: I wrote :
TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arg1'

I would expect it to get memoized , meaning to be stored at the cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `@Memoized` class replaces (wraps) the `GetData2()` function and shadows it with itself, being a callable which takes `*args`, but no `**kwargs`.

A possible solution could be

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print args
    with Locker:
        kwitems = tuple(sorted(kwargs.items()))
        try:
            return self.cache[args, kwitems]
        except KeyError:
            self.cache[args, kwitems] = value = self.func(*args)
            return value
```

But then it makes a difference for the cache if you call it with

```
GetData2(1, 2, 3)
```

or with

```
GetData2(arg1=1, arg2=2, arg3=3)
```

or any other combination.

The call path is:

```
    wrapped GetData2()
--> Memoized.__call__()
--> self.func()
--> original GetData2()
```

Comment: I am curious about `self.cache[args, kwargs]`. `kwargs` is a `dict` and unhashable. Therefore, `(args, kwargs)` cannot be used as a key. This `__call__` will probably yield `TypeError as well.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least there's a problem in how you pass parameters to `__call__()`. Try changing the `*args` in your `__call()__`-function to `**args`. This means that instead of passing an arbitary tuple of arguments you'll pass keyword arguments as a dictionary.

```
class Memoized(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, **args):
        print args
        ....
```

This will then result in something like this:

```
In [16]: GetData2(**r)
{'arg1': 'hello', 'arg2': 67, 'arg3': 8.3}
```

However this might change the way you expect your caching routine to work.